# Angular 2 passing arguments to a component during init()

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to understand the concept of passing arguments to a Component which have 1 - required, 2- not required/optional.
Lets say I have two files:

#### app1.comp.ts

Lets say this is the first component that is including `App2Comp`

```
export class App1Comp {

  // try 1
  // How the hell I pass my _properties variable to App2Comp ?
  constructor(private MyApp2 : App2Comp) {}


  // try 2
  constructor() {
      // Initialize the parameter inside the constructor
      // This gives an error that the call does not match the function's
      // Signature - that's because I never gave a value for:
      // LocalStorage & broadcaster ... ( which I can't - they don't need )
      this.MyApp2 = new App2Comp({  arg1 : 60 });

      // This didn't work either
      this.MyApp2 = new App2Comp(_properties={  arg1 : 60 });
  }
}
```

#### app2.comp.ts

So this is what I'm trying to do - have all arguments in the header of the `constractor`

```
export class App2Comp {

  // Doesn't work
  // mostly because an optional parameter doesn't come before required
  // ones
  constructor(public _properties? : any, private LocalStorage : LocalStorageService, private broadcaster : Broadcaster) {
  }

  // Also placing the _properties at the end of the required ones and
  // calling in app1.comp.ts with - also doesn't work:
  // this.temp = new App2Comp(_properties=this.properties);  

  // This type of writing, causing an error of:
  // LocalStorage & broadcaster are undefined 
  constructor(public _properties? : any, private LocalStorage? : LocalStorageService, private broadcaster? : Broadcaster) {
  }
}
```

For example, try to compare it to a Python like class where you can mix required argument and optional argument while init()

```
// Python example
def init(self, arg1, arg2, opt1=12, opt2=None)
```

So my `_properties` - is optional, while `LocalStorage` and `broadcaster` are required.

#### The temp solution I found ( app2.comp.ts )

The solution I found for now ( but I'm not very pleased about it ) -is:

```
export class App2Comp {
  LocalStorage : any;
  broadcaster  : any;

  constructor(public _properties? : any) {
      this.LocalStorage = new LocalStorageService();
      this.broadcaster  = new Broadcaster;

      if ( _properties ) {
          // do some code here
      }
  }
}
```

So I need someone to clarify the proper way of initializing a component with parameters ( required / optionals etc .. ) or maybe my current solution - is the only way to properly do that... ?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend passing in the properties as an input in your markup.

In your child component, declare an `@Input`. For example:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'cool-component',
  template: `
    <p>{{JSON.stringify(properties)}}.</p>
  `
})
export class CoolComponent {
  // If an input is specified when the component is used it will
  // override this default.
  @Input() properties: any = { defaultKey: 'defaultValue' };
}
```

Then in your parent component you can simply pass the information to the child component via markup.

```
<cool-component [properties]="_properties"></cool-component>
```

For more information check out: 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I saw a couple of examples doing this, the problem that doesn't match my component - is the fact that it cannot be a directive ( html tag ) it's a timer component which exists in the entire app ( not in a specific page ) - you know what I mean ? and the code should exists everywhere

Comment: This is why my question was about passing arguments from component - to a another component ( vs initialize a component with arguments in general )

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. If you put your timer into an Angular service (using dependency injection) then you can share a singleton with your entire application. Have your child component simply inject the global service and avoid passing it in all together.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: The component is shared with the app, but it's not singleton, it's the same `Timer` but I want to have two `Timer`s - they are differentiate by a key ( or `id` or something ), eventually what I did was to initialize the component/service, afterwards I have a function called `myapp2.setID(someID)` which will give me the right object to work with ... but it's not straight forward as well ...